# YARN TimeLine Server in AWS EMR do not show logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have added a step in aws emr which is failing in execution.

But on trying to check YARN logs I see error message as

'Cannot get container logs. Invalid nodeId'
[image]

Any help on how to get logs in YARN web UI.

Comment: I suggest contacting EMR support